# PHP functions for mysql assoc_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to improve my skillset so on a new project by trying to store most actions as functions to minimize repetitive code.

Previously all my code was in the header of each PHP file (a la Dreamweaver style)

On this new project, I have a page that needs to pull an associative array to display a blog.

Its failing currently. Here is what I have:

**DB.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function getAllBlogs()
{   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            return $result;
}
```

**blog.php**

```
<?php include("../Connections/db.php");?>
<?php include("functions.php");?>
    <?php 
            $result = getAllBlogs();
    foreach($result as $blogs) {
     echo "/".$blogs['id']."_".seoUrl($blogs['title']);
    }
    ?>
```

**Do I need to include the db.php in the functions file?**

Obviously, I am not putting all code as some is HTML for styling but this is what I am getting as far as errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home/classbyt/public_html/functions.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/classbyt/public_html/functions.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/classbyt/public_html/functions.php on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/classbyt/public_html/blog.php on line 33
```

LINE 33 on BLOG.php is

```
foreach($result as $blogs) {
```

LINE 17 & 18 on functions.php is

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

Comment: What message you are getting? Please share here.

Comment: include functions.php in blog.php and check. write include_once('functions.php'); on top of blog.php

Comment: Guessing it could be a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue

Comment: 1. Need to be `$result = getAllBlogs();` 2. You're only fetching one row

Comment: Thank you all. going to post a full reply below.

Comment: If you really want to clean this up, consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/)
like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) which provides a structure you can build on rather than having to invent your own. Applications composed of seemingly random PHP files all inter-linked in a non-standard way are extremely difficult to maintain. Most frameworks have a router component that serves as an entry point for your application rather than having to create many different PHP files to represent each "page".

Answer (score 0):

The method getAllBlogs() do not have a variable for the return value.

```
<?php

$result = getAllBlogs();

foreach($result as $blogs) 
{
    echo "/".$blogs['id']."_".seoUrl($blogs['title']);
} 

?>
```

**Edit:**

You have a scope problem with your $conn. Your mysqli_query() method don't know the $conn variable.

**functions.php**

```
function getAllBlogs()
{   
    global $conn; // -> to get access to the variable, which is outside the method
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to include more information and errors .

Answer (score 0):

You forget to assign  it into $result variable

```
 <?php
        $result=getAllBlogs();// assign to $result variable
        foreach($result as $blogs) {
       echo "/".$blogs['id']."_".seoUrl($blogs['title']);
     } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to include more information and errors .

Answer (score 0):

first include the functions.php file in blog.php. The use the below code.

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';
$result = getAllBlogs();

foreach($result as $blogs) 
{
    echo "/".$blogs['id']."_".seoUrl($blogs['title']);
} 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to include more information and errors .